# Venturi Effect?

Tags: speed

I was rinsing out my recyclables when it seemed to me that a 24 oz. plastic bottle drained A LOT faster than a 12 oz. can when held upside down. So I tried it again and sure enough the 24 oz. bottle drained a lot quicker than the can. If I had to guesstimate, I would say the bottle drained twice as fast as the can. I was wondering if the venturi effect is what's occurring and would any volume greater than the 12 oz. can drain faster than the can? Or does it depend on the size of the restriction/opening and its location.  Would a 36 oz. bottle drain 3 times as fast as the can? What if there was a vent in the can above the water line. Would that allow the can to drain faster than the bottle? I can't imagine a gallon milk container emptying faster than a 12 oz. can.  Thank you in advance for your responses.